# How to get bare wsgi stream in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, werkzeug

Using Flask, I'd like to get at the bare wsgi.input reference. Looking at the code, there seems to be more than one way to do this, both of which appear in:

```
werkzeug.wsgi.get_input_stream(environ, safe_fallback=True):
    ...
    if environ.get('wsgi.input_terminated'):
        return stream
    ...
    if content_length is None:
        return safe_fallback and _empty_stream or stream
    ...
```

Annoyingly I can't figure out how to actually get either of these cases to happen (and they're barely mentioned in the docs).

wsgi.input_terminated: I know I can set the wsgi environment if I'm using a proper server like Apache but how do I do it under the Flask dev server, given that Werkzeug hard codes its wsgi environment in werkzeug.serving.make_environ()?

safe_fallback: Can't figure this at all... what's this parameter doing here if it's just called by itself and never passed? How am I supposed to activate it?

Quite possibly missing something easy here...

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? The 'wsgi.input_terminated' value in Flask is not a part of the official WSGI specification and you wouldn't want to rely on it. The real input stream is 'wsgi.input'.

Comment: Just trying to get the input stream - perhaps I wasn't clear but wsgi.input_terminated is just a bool (effectively) that determines what the helper in Flask returns; the stream or its own wrapped stream (the wrapper seems to exhaust the stream in all cases). I could rephrase the question as "how do I get the input stream before Flask empties it".

Comment: The 'wsgi.input_terminated' is a Flask web server extension so that Flask knows it is dealing with a WSGI server that can handle chunked request content, something that is technically not supported under the WSGI specification. It causes it to ignore ``CONTENT_LENGTH``.

Comment: Anyway, can't you see ``wsgi.input`` in ``request.environ``? Still not clear on what the problem is you are trying to solve. You are asking how to solve problems with your solution. What is the problem with the way Flask normally deals with request content that requires dropping down to ``wsgi.input``.

Comment: OK so I want to be able to pipe data from the wsgi input into another binary (what that does isn't terribly interesting but its a different protocol to do with some backup software). So in other words a kind of stream proxy. In order to keep it scalable I'd like to be able to pass it over 100KB or so at a time. Sadly, neither streaming or chunking seems to keep the data out of memory (or at least a temp file). So since I only need to do one task with the data, I thought I might write my own stream wrapper to read x bytes at a time until an EOF occurs. Flask seems to have some of the equipment.

Comment: And you can't you see ``wsgi.input`` in ``request.environ``? That is where I would expect to see it.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right, I can do that and just re-wrap it with the same wrapper. That way I get to keep all the bells and whistles, I just have to write my own read loop, which is fine. I had been approaching it from the angle of using the parameters that I found in the code, but I think they're kinda half done and not really usable. Thanks Graham.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly more elaborate version of the function @javabrett suggested in his comment to @ddzialek's answer.  This one checks for chunked input before setting the flag (I'm not positive that's necessary, but it doesn't seem like a great idea to set a flag you might not need).

```
@app.before_request
def handle_chunking():
    """
    Sets the "wsgi.input_terminated" environment flag, thus enabling
    Werkzeug to pass chunked requests as streams; this makes the API
    compliant with the HTTP/1.1 standard.  The gunicorn server should set
    the flag, but this feature has not been implemented.
    """

    transfer_encoding = request.headers.get("Transfer-Encoding", None)
    if transfer_encoding == "chunked":
        request.environ["wsgi.input_terminated"] = True
```

The value of "Transfer-Encoding" that actually comes through will probably be in Unicode rather than ASCII, hence "u'chunked'" would be more accurate--but for characters in the ASCII range, the difference is irrelevant (Python will match the strings either way), and Python 3 doesn't need the "u".

EDIT:  It's important to note that some WSGI servers no longer require this fix.  Specifically, `gunicorn` has respected the `wsgi.input_terminated` flag since version 20.0, though it should be noted that 20.0 was the first version that didn't support Python 2.x--so if you're stuck using Python 2.x, you'll still need this fix.

Comment: The ``Transfer-Encoding`` heading be set to ``chunked`` doesn't imply you can set ``wsgi.input_terminated`` yourself. Whether that can be done depends on how the WSGI server is implemented. Up to date versions of the major WSGI servers now support setting ``wsgi.input_terminated`` themselves when appropriate, so you shouldn't need to.

Comment: I understand that the server is _supposed_ to set it, but the fact of the matter is that gunicorn doesn't do so--and setting it yourself, when appropriate, does in fact fix the problem (the code above is from a Flask service that currently up and running and works fine).

Comment: Strange, as I thought I recollect a twitter discussion a while back that gunicorn authors said that the setting of the flag was being added. Unless they decided not to or haven't released a new version since.

Comment: Here's the open issue:  https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1653.  They were originally going to fix the problem in a release in mid-December (2017), but this was postponed:  https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1634.  I believe the sticking point (referenced in the first link above) is a fear that adding stream support without a request size limit would create a vulnerability to DoS attacks.  (In my case, it's not an issue--we're planning to reverse-proxy the API with NGINX, and NGINX can set the size limit.)

Comment: I can't see that the DoS attack is related to this specific change. The DoS attack they mention is Sloworis which is already an issue. So long as gunicorn doesn't buffer chunked request content, which I don't believe it does, there shouldn't be an issue with ``wsgi.input_terminated``. Looks to me simply like had some reservations and so deferred it and haven't gone back to revisit it.

Comment: I like the pragmatic approach @MTKnife, just solved my issue with your code snippet. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I know it's pretty old thread but I've found one way to handle chunked encoding requests (I need to have stream not data) and within custom python application (gunicorn + flask), so instead of using `flask.Flask` as app I've created subclass:

```
class FlaskApp(flask.Flask):
    def request_context(self, environ):
        # it's the only way I've found to handle chunked encoding request (otherwise flask.request.stream is empty)
        environ['wsgi.input_terminated'] = 1
        return super(FlaskApp, self).request_context(environ)
```

Anyone has better idea how to do that in a better way?

Comment: Could avoid a subclass by adding a `@app.before_request def before_request(): request.environ['wsgi.input_terminated'] = 1`

Answer (score 1):

The solution @ddzialak posted works, but reading the stream with either request.stream.read(chunk_size) or request.get_data() gives the complete stream's content, including headers.  Here is what I use to get my tools the information they use:

```
str_data    = request.get_data() # stream data
pattern = re.compile(r'\r\n\r\n(.+?)\n\r\n', flags=re.DOTALL) # content regex
file_data   = pattern.findall( str_data.decode('UTF-8') )[0] # what my tools use
```